# Symfony2 Form: How to display all the errors?

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I want to print all the validation errors together, and not each error next to each field.

But form_errors(form) isn't working.

I can print individual errors, so I thought I could just use form_errors(form.some_field) for each field. The problem is that it prints errors like 'This field cannot be blank', which is meaningless unless it is next to the field.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Then change the error message for the field... http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/validation.html#constraint-configuration.

Comment: A framework shouldn't require that I do that -.-

Comment: Okay I guess I do not get the point... What difference does it make if you aggregate the errors when they still read "'This field cannot be blank'"?.

Comment: I mean that for base errors (ie: the ones related to the default validation options, like 'NotBlank'/'This field cant be blank'), I shouldn't have to rewrite all the messages, in each language.

Answer (score 4):

You should look the `error_bubbling` field property. If you set that property true, any errors for this field will be passed to the parent field or form.

For example, if set to true on a normal field, any errors for that field will be attached to the main form, not to the specific field.